# Sending data from C# to Javascript in a WPF application

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf

I have a WPF application. In MainWindow.xaml.cs, there is an object named Person. Person has "Name" field. In MainWindow.xaml, I have a  window.That window goes to a webpage that I created. I want to see the "Name" of the Person in that webpage. How can I pass the info in C# to JavaScript page? Thanks.

Comment: Could you pass the name via the URL query string?

Comment: @JonHunter Can I do that in WPF? Can URL change dynamically in <WebBrowser Source> ?

Comment: You can set the web browser "source" property dynamically in you C# code, e.g. webBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com")

Comment: @JonHunter Thanks, I did it code-behind. But it didn't work. I get this error : System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.Source' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Can you post your code pls?

Comment: in xaml : <WebBrowser Name="browse"/>
code behind :  WebBrowser.Source = new Uri("google.com");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the web browser "source" property dynamically in you C# code so you should be able to pass information to the website using the querystring.

For example if your xaml is:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Source="" />
```

You can set the source using:

```
webBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com/?myval=value");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("JavaScriptfunctionName", new Object[] { Parameter1, Parameter2});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Awesomium which even as a WPF control built-in. It's every easy to you. Check the this link: http://wiki.awesomium.net/

Then you can call any JS functions from C# and pass parameters to it. The call would then look like this:

```
JSValue param = new JSValue("a name");
webView.CallJavascriptFunction("test", "displayName", param);
```